# React native | Error running Expo | Unhandled error event

Tags: react-native, expo

I was just working on my react-native app using expo when suddenly my app stopped working.

When I tried to restart my app it seemed as if`expo` had been removed from my computer, because when I run expo start I get an error message:

```
'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then When I run `npm install`

It does seem to finish it up stating at the end

```
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 14262 packages in 23.291s
found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

But then when I run `Npm start`

I got asked the question:

```
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]?
```

To which I respond with `Y`

Which then responds with :

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:235:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the empty-project-template@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Volks-laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-12T21_37_46_094Z-debug.log
```

I tried removing the `package-lock.json` file and running `npm install`

I tried removing `Node_module` folder  and running `npm install`

I tried both and running `npm install`

What Caused this error? And how can I fix this?

**What Am I expecting? **

When I run `Expo start` my expo CLI to start working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough I found a post saying that restarting my laptop would help and strangely enough after restarting my laptop and running expo cli install command solved my problem